# Extracting multiple text from excel cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following text in a column

`CLIENT_REGION_PLACEMENT_STAGE_(T1-AUDTYPE)_(T2-AUD)_(T4-GENDER)_(T6-ACTION)_(D-DM)_(C1-TYPE)_(C2-NAME)_(C3-NAME2)_(C4-DATE)_(C5-MEDIA)_(A-ATYPE)`

How would I go about extracting the various bits of text into separate columns so that any data attached to that text can be segmented by the various sections (e.g. in a pviot). For example the following would all go into separate columns:

```
CLIENT
REGION
PLACEMENT
etc

T1-AUDTYPE
T2-AUD
etc

C1-TYPE
C2-NAME
etc
```

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! What is the criteria to divide/extract the text? What have tried to extract the text?

Comment: You probably should look at "Text to Columns"  ( https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/use-text-columns-excel )   but your text appears tricky so you may need a few tries to get it right or even do an iterative approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that both the headers *and* the data beneath are underscore-separated, select the column that currently contains the data and use Data>Data Tools>Text to Columns.

On Step 1 of the Convert Text to Columns Wizard, select Delimited and click Next.

On Step 2, select Other then enter an underscore in the box next to Other:

[image]

Click Next.

On Step 3, you can optionally select each column in turn and adjust the Column data format and decide whether or not to skip certain columns.

Click Finish to close the wizard.

At this point, if you want to remove the parentheses from the T1-etc fields, you can use Find & Replace - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

EDIT:

To avoid separation of legitimate underscores, surround field names with a text-qualifier. So, replace ( and ) with " before you start. You can see that T2-AUD_2 is treated as a field correctly:

[image]

Comment: I did originally try this but annoyingly some of the data within the parentheses has underscores e.g. (T2-AUD_2) so it ends up splitting that data, too!

Comment: In that case, before using text-to-columns as described above, replace the `(` and `)` with `"`. Since the text qualifier is `"`, it will not treat items within two text qualifiers as a separator.

Comment: Ah brilliant, such a simple solution! Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful. If this has resolved your challenge, please considering upvoting and accepting my answer to your question. For more information, you can read here: https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Done :) Additionally, do you know if there's a way to automate this so that if I paste that data into one column, other designated columns (C1, C2, etc) automatically check the pasted data and extract the information, then populate under the relevant column? Not all of these titles have all the columns e.g. Some may have C1 and C2 but not C3 or C6. That means using the above method requires further clean up of the data (moving items from column to column until it is under the right section.